# XSD all plus any without sequence

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I have a complextype element :

```
<mytype>
    <key1>required</key1>
    <key2>optional</key2>
    <anyotherkey>whatever type value</anyotherkey>
</mytype>
```

Basically,  I have an element with a required key (key1),  an optional key (key2), and other keys, I don't care.   How to write a valid xsd?

`<xs:all>` can only validate (key1 + key2), but not "anyotherkey" because the name of "anyotherkey" can be any name.
`<xs:any>` in `<xs:sequence>` looks promising, but the problem is that "anyotherkeys" can be in any order.  I don't want a specific sequence.  For exmaple below, it is still a valid data:

```
<mytype>
    <key3>key3 value</key3>
    <key1>key1 value</key1>
    <key2>key2 value</key2>
</mytype>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `xs:any` inside `xs:all`. Furthermore, you have to choose a (different) namespace for `xs:any` if you want to put it together with `xs:element` in one level.

The most practical way in my opinion is to have a less restrictive XML Schema and add further sanity checks after parsing (e. g., Java, Schematron, ...):

```
 <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            elementFormDefault="qualified" 
            targetNamespace="http://ns-main"> 
    <xs:complexType name="register">
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="key1" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="key2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:any namespace="http://ns-opt" processContents="lax"/>
        </xs:choice>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Note that you probably want to have `processContents='lax'` for `xs:any`, otherwise the XML parser has to know Schema definitions at runtime for all elements for `xs:any`, too.

That allows you instances such as (assuming main:test has type main:register).

```
<main:test xmlns:main="http://ns-main"  xmlns:opt="http://ns-opt">
    <main:key2>test</main:key2>
    <opt:key3>test</opt:key3>
    <main:key1>test</main:key1>   
</main:test>
```

If you cannot change the namespaces of your data, I am afraid that there is no other XML schema than

```
<xs:complexType name="register">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any namespace="##any" processContents="lax" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence> 
</xs:complexType>
```